# Is there an adjective meaning "that which provides insight" with a negative or neural connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Consider the sentence (1):

> The Allies reprinted Axis propaganda during WWII, and the Axis reprinted Allied propaganda. There were some exceptions, but clearly they saw [adjective] value in the documents.

or similarly (2):

> The Allies reprinted Axis propaganda during WWII, and the Axis reprinted Allied propaganda. There were some exceptions, but clearly they found the documents [adjective].

The [adjective] I'm looking for has the approximate meaning of "that which provides insights [into enemy motivations]". The best options I've been able to come up with thus far are:

- *probative* or *expository* in (1), which aren't great matches
- *forensic* in (1), which seems far too formal
- *enlightening* or *insightful* in (2), which carry the strong connotation of agreeing with or being swayed by the propaganda and therefore aren't suitable here

I have a niggling suspicion that there *is* a single adjective closer to the intended meaning but my mental thesaurus fails me.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to find anything really negative, but ***instructive*** feels at least neutral.

> serving to instruct or inform; conveying instruction, knowledge, or information

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/instructive)

However, I do think use of terms such as ***enlightening*** or ***edifying*** could be used in an ironic manner, using opposite ideas to show the nefarious intention.

Comment: The problem I have "instructive" is the same as for "insightful". Namely, that "I found the pamphlet instructive." to me implies that I accepted the instruction the pamphlet had to offer. "I found the ISIS propaganda instructive." would probably raise a few worried eyebrows. Would you not agree?

Comment: To me, "instructive" is academic and sterile. If someone told me they found ISIS propaganda to be instructive, I would think they are trying to find a way to put the fact that they read ISIS propaganda into as neutral a way as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The least positive I can think of is ***revealing***.  Alternatively, there is ***informative***, which is along the same lines as *enlightening*, but probably a bit more neutral.  These both work better in sentence (2).